# cross building binutils 2.25.1 for iOS8.4 (arm64-apple-darwin14.0.0)

Tags: ios, cross-compiling, arm64, binutils

**EDIT. 2015-30-10.** I tried this :

```
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/GNU-CROSS/binutils-2.25.1/ CC="clang -fembed-bitcode -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -mios-version-min=8.4 -no-integrated-as -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-darwin" CPP="clang -E" CPPFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -mios-version-min=8.4 -no-integrated-as -arch arm64 -target arm64-apple-darwin" --host=aarch64-apple-darwin --disable-assembly --enable-static --disable-shared
make -j 4
```

Configuring went ok, but the `make` triggered this :

```
BFD does not support target aarch64-apple-darwin
```

---

**Initial question.**

I am trying to cross-build binutils 2.25.1 for an iOS (8.4) 64 bits target. I put the binutils-2.25.1 folder on the target and the config.guess script which gave me arm64-apple-darwin14.0.0. On my host (x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0) I created a build folder inside binutils-2.25.1 and ran there :

```
CCFLAGS="--arch arm64" LDFLAGS="--arch arm64" ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/lvm-cross/ --host=arm-apple-darwin
```

which gave me this :

```
configure: error: in `/Users/XXXX/Documents/src/gcc-5.2.0-cross/binutils-2.25.1/build':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

All details are in the config.log file at the end.

My question is the following : *how can I build binutils for this 64bits target ?*

The config.log file contains this :

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/lvm-cross/ --host=arm-apple-darwin

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = XXXXs-MacBook-Air.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 14.4.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 239 tasks, 978 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.62, Mach factor: 2.37
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /sw/bin
PATH: /sw/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin
PATH: /usr/local/git/bin
PATH: /Library/TeX/texbin
PATH: /Users/XXXX/.opam/4.02.2/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2322: checking build system type
configure:2336: result: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
configure:2383: checking host system type
configure:2396: result: arm-apple-darwin
configure:2416: checking target system type
configure:2429: result: arm-apple-darwin
configure:2483: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2551: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2562: checking whether ln works
configure:2584: result: yes
configure:2588: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2592: result: yes
configure:2599: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2663: result: /usr/bin/sed
configure:2672: checking for gawk
configure:2702: result: no
configure:2672: checking for mawk
configure:2702: result: no
configure:2672: checking for nawk
configure:2702: result: no
configure:2672: checking for awk
configure:2688: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:2699: result: awk
configure:3941: checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc
configure:3971: result: no
configure:3981: checking for gcc
configure:3997: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4008: result: gcc
configure:4237: checking for C compiler version
configure:4246: gcc --version >&5
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
configure:4257: $? = 0
configure:4246: gcc -v >&5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
configure:4257: $? = 0
configure:4246: gcc -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:4257: $? = 1
configure:4246: gcc -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang: error: no input files
configure:4257: $? = 1
configure:4277: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4299: gcc   --arch arm64 conftest.c  >&5
clang: error: unsupported option '--arch'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'arm64'
configure:4303: $? = 1
configure:4340: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4346: error: in `/Users/XXXX/Documents/src/gcc-5.2.0-cross/binutils-2.25.1/build':
configure:4350: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AR_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_value=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='--arch arm64'
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-apple-darwin
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_value=
ac_cv_host=arm-apple-darwin
ac_cv_path_SED=/usr/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_target=arm-apple-darwin
acx_cv_prog_LN=ln

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
AR_FOR_BUILD='ar'
AR_FOR_TARGET=''
AS=''
AS_FOR_BUILD='as'
AS_FOR_TARGET=''
AWK='awk'
BISON=''
BUILD_CONFIG=''
CC='gcc'
CC_FOR_BUILD='gcc'
CC_FOR_TARGET=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET=''
CONFIGURE_GDB_TK=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
CXX_FOR_BUILD='g++'
CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD='dlltool'
DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPECT=''
EXTRA_CONFIGARGS_LIBJAVA='--disable-static'
FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
FLEX=''
GCC_FOR_TARGET=''
GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
GCJ_FOR_BUILD='gcj'
GCJ_FOR_TARGET=''
GDB_TK=''
GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD='gfortran'
GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET=''
GNATBIND=''
GNATMAKE=''
GOC_FOR_BUILD='gccgo'
GOC_FOR_TARGET=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LD=''
LDFLAGS='--arch arm64'
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
LD_FOR_BUILD='ld'
LD_FOR_TARGET=''
LEX=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO=''
LIPO_FOR_TARGET=''
LN='ln'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
M4=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO=''
NM=''
NM_FOR_BUILD='nm'
NM_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
RANLIB_FOR_BUILD='ranlib'
RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=''
RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
READELF=''
READELF_FOR_TARGET=''
RPATH_ENVVAR=''
RUNTEST=''
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
STRIP_FOR_TARGET=''
SYSROOT_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS='../configure --prefix=/usr/local/lvm-cross/ --host=arm-apple-darwin'
WINDMC=''
WINDMC_FOR_BUILD='windmc'
WINDMC_FOR_TARGET=''
WINDRES=''
WINDRES_FOR_BUILD='windres'
WINDRES_FOR_TARGET=''
YACC=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0'
build_alias=''
build_configargs=''
build_configdirs='build-libiberty build-texinfo build-flex build-bison build-m4 build-fixincludes'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_libsubdir='build-x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0'
build_noncanonical='x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0'
build_os='darwin14.4.0'
build_subdir='build-x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0'
build_tooldir=''
build_vendor='apple'
clooginc=''
clooglibs=''
compare_exclusions=''
configdirs='intl libiberty opcodes bfd readline tcl tk itcl libgui zlib libbacktrace libcpp libdecnumber gmp mpfr mpc isl cloog libelf libiconv texinfo flex bison binutils gas ld fixincludes gcc cgen sid sim gdb gprof etc expect dejagnu m4 utils guile fastjar gnattools'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
do_compare=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags=''
extra_isl_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags=''
extra_mpfr_configure_flags=''
gmpinc=''
gmplibs=''
host='arm-apple-darwin'
host_alias='arm-apple-darwin'
host_configargs=''
host_cpu='arm'
host_noncanonical='arm-apple-darwin'
host_os='darwin'
host_shared=''
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
islinc=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
poststage1_ldflags=''
poststage1_libs=''
prefix='/usr/local/lvm-cross'
program_transform_name='s,y,y,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
stage1_cflags=''
stage1_checking=''
stage1_languages=''
stage1_ldflags=''
stage1_libs=''
stage2_werror_flag=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='arm-apple-darwin'
target_alias=''
target_configargs=''
target_configdirs='target-libgcc target-libbacktrace target-libgloss target-newlib target-libgomp target-libcilkrts target-libatomic target-libitm target-libstdc++-v3 target-libsanitizer target-libvtv target-libssp target-libquadmath target-libgfortran target-boehm-gc target-libffi target-zlib target-libjava target-libobjc target-libada target-libgo target-rda'
target_cpu='arm'
target_noncanonical='arm-apple-darwin'
target_os='darwin'
target_subdir='arm-apple-darwin'
target_vendor='apple'
tooldir=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

alphaieee_frag=''
host_makefile_frag='config/mh-darwin'
ospace_frag=''
serialization_dependencies=''
target_makefile_frag=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** I think you will probably never see any `binutils` release targeting iOS.

1. Apple never made the specifications of Mach-O on iOS open.
2. It is unlikely you can get code that contains `libbfd` into App Store (since it is explicitly pointed out that GNU GPL is fundamentally incompatible with App Store regulation, especially in the VLC for iOS controversy)
3. It is unlikely you can get code compiled with anything other than Apple's version of `clang` into App Store (explicitly prohibited by the App Store Review Guidelines)
4. Even when targeting OS X, `binutils` is not capable of actually linking and building code.

If you are targeting iOS, you will have to use the toolchain Apple provided, or build your own equivalent from the source code Apple released (`ld`, `clang` and LLVM are all open-source projects, while the underlying iOS libraries can be copied over from a Mac albeit for your own personal use only).